# matlab - combine all the output using celldisp

Tags: matlab, for-loop

Below is my code.. I'm trying to display each of the seq using celldisp..but it comes out one by one..

```
%mycode

seq1 = {'acc';'gct';'tta';'ccc';'ttc';'aaa';'ttg';'gta';'gtg';'act'};
seq2 = {'act';'gcc';'tta';'cca';'aac';'aaa';'ttg';'gta';'gtg';'acc'};
seq3 = {'ttc';'tgc';'atg';'ggc';'ccg';'aat';'aag';'ggt';'tga';'agt'};
seq4 = {'cag';'ccg';'ttg';'caa';'aat';'agc';'ttg';'ggg';'gct';'att'};
seq5 = {'ccc';'ggg';'tta';'cag';'aac';'aaa';'ttg';'gta';'gac';'acc'};
seq6 = {'acc';'gct';'ata';'ccc';'ttc';'taa';'ttg';'gtc';'gtg';'acc'};

for mutseq = {seq2,seq3,seq4,seq5,seq6}
    a = strcmp(seq1,mutseq);
    celldisp(mutseq);        
end

%endcode
```

the output is :

```
mutseq{1}{1} =
act

mutseq{1}{2} =
gcc 

mutseq{1}{3} =
tta

mutseq{1}{4} =
cca 

mutseq{1}{5} =
aac 

mutseq{1}{6} =
aaa


mutseq{1}{7} = 
ttg

mutseq{1}{8} =
gta 

mutseq{1}{9} =
gtg

mutseq{1}{10} =
```

%and it repeat for next seq

did anyone know how to combine it into one?

Comment: Can't you use disp(mutseq{:}) for instance?

Comment: How exactly do you want this to be displayed?  I don't quite understand what you're asking here.

Comment: i want to display it in a row